# Query Parameter vs URI path in POST Request Python Flask Service

Tags: python, http, post, flask

Is there a way to do something of this sort in Python Flask?
I want my URI to be in the following way:

```
POST /myModel/{location}/getValue
{ //Has some Data
}
```

Is it possible to define a API like this and determine the location or should I pass it as a query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Look at examples for [@route decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#url-route-registrations)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `default` params in your URL

```
@app.route('/users/', defaults={'page': 1})
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>')
def show_users(page):
    pass
```

From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#url-route-registrations). So in your case the `page` route could be a flexible parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can define methods for your routes and handle data in Flask like so:

```
@app.route('/myModel/<location>/getValue', methods = ['POST'])
def my_route(location):
    request_location = location  # will contain location
    request_data = request.form  # will contain data from request
    # rest of the code goes here
```